# Need a little help with SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose, I have an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, object>>` and that I want to replace for each element of the enumeration the first element by a list of (several) other elements:

```
Original enumerable: { { "a", obj1 }, { "b", obj2 } }
First-element replacement: a -> { "c", "d" }, b -> { "e", "f", "g" }
Result : { { "c", obj1 }, { "d", obj1 }, { "e", obj2 }, { "f" , obj2 }, { "g" , obj2 } }
```

How can I accomplish this with `SelectMany` in a better way than

```
enumerable.SelectMany(item => ReplacementFunction(item.Item1).Select(newItem =>
new Tuple<string, object>(newItem, item.Item2)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'd probably use a query expression instead:

```
var query = from tuple in enumerable
            from replacement in ReplacementFunction(tuple.Item1)
            select Tuple.Create(replacement, tuple.Item2);
```

But that's *basically* the same thing...